# IELTS for Tier 2 General visa

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, visa

I want to apply for "Tier2 General" visa for the UK.
According to the embassy's website, I need to prove my English skills.
They need IELTS in level B1.
There are 2type of IELTS exam:

1. IELTS UKVI General training
2. IELTS General

I know that the first one is acceptable for the visa.

I want to know that is this possible to pass the English requirement by the second one or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on expartes.SE

Comment: @A.K. It belongs to the law. Lawyers who have experience in the immigration process can answer this question. So I don't think that this question is off-topic and your reason is not acceptable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the following site, it should count:
https://www.ielts.org/what-is-ielts/ielts-for-migration/united-kingdom